# Compare several columns of gene names

Tags: r, compare

I have several columns of genes symbol in which I would like to check whether which genes is similar in each column

for example a three columns as follows

```
ADORA2B      ADORA2B    KLC1
AGPAT5       HOPX       LEPR
ASS1         IGFBP7     LTBP3
C1QBP        INHBA      MBNL2
C4orf19      ITGB5      MLLT11
CASP1        ITGBL1     NOTCH3
CASP1        ITGBL1     NPR3
CASP1                   NUAK1
CASP1                   OLR1
CCL20                   PDGFC
KBTBD11                 PLA2G16
KLF4        
ME2     
MPDU1       
NAT1        
PBK     
PSMB10      
PSMB8       
PSMB9
```

Comment: @Frank , I am mainly working with R. I amended the question a bit. I am searching to plot a plot like Fig1B of the following paper too 

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20926834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this simple situation with 3 columns, you could simply do the following:

```
intersect(a,b)
#[1] "ADORA2B"
intersect(a,d)
#character(0)
intersect(b,d)
#character(0)
```

If you have a lot more gene sets, you might want a different approach.  Something like this could work, though there are surely better solutions:

```
# Gather up all the vectors you want to use
sets <- c("a","b","d")
# Make all possible pairs of sets
combos <- combn(sets,2)
# look for shared strings between all possible pairs of sets
sapply(1:ncol(combos), function(x) intersect(get(combos[1,x]), get(combos[2,x])))
#[[1]]
#[1] "ADORA2B"
#
#[[2]]
#character(0)
#
#[[3]]
#character(0)
```